# Can someone please identify this plant?

Tags: identification

This plant is in Melbourne, Australia. Thought it was a lilac but not quite.
[image]

Comment: Is this blooming like this NOW?  Buddleia is incredibly tough and can reseed quite readily.  This is breathtaking!  After this is done blooming you should then prune out old, old wood.  Flowers on second year growth.  Train into a multistemmed small tree (my fav way) or single stemmed tree.  Gorgeous!  How big is this plant, now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [buddleja salviiflora](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddleja_salviifolia), or "South African sage bush" or "wild lilac" or "butterfly bush", a plant native to Southern and Eastern Africa.

The lilac-like, fragrant inflorescence and sage-like leaves are quite distinct and one reason that buddleja salviiflora (and other buddlejas) are favourites in parks and gardens around the world. They deal well with lean soil and occasional droughts and grow rapidly and strongly, making them relatively low maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks a lot like Hardenbergia violacea. However your flowers look a little different. Perhaps it's related to this plant.

Comment: Yes it does indeed but the flower shape is quite different. I compared many images of Hardenbergia violacea and no it is not. But anyway thank you Rain.